# ¿Como puedo dejar que el usuario decida las dimensiones de la matriz y mantener la diagonal de 1?

Tags: c++

Pues eso, ya tengo hecho el código que me permite crear una matriz que se imprima como una tabla de ceros con el valor 1 siempre presentándose en la diagonal de la tabla, pero ahora quiero permitir que el usuario pueda decidir el tamaño de la matriz manteniendo esta condición de que el valor 1 siempre debe estar en la diagonal. Saludos.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Matriz[5][5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            Matriz[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    Matriz[0][0]=1;
    Matriz[1][1]=1;
    Matriz[1][1]=1;
    Matriz[2][2]=1;
    Matriz[3][3]=1;
    Matriz[4][4]=1;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
                cout<<Matriz[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de `int Matriz[5][5];` tendrías que hacer una inicializacion dinamica, como:

```
    int **matriz = NULL;
    matriz = new int*[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      matriz[i] = new int[n];
    }
```